derivating matrices for Karush-Kuhn-Tucker
I am trying to solve a Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) over a number of observations. I am not strong with Matrices derivatives. For a single datapoint $p_i = (p_i,c_i)$, and a constant $c_0$, I can estimate the $c_i$ value using $\bar{c_i} = p_i + u + s(c_0 - p_i)$. Hence, I am looking for the optimal values of $(u,s)$ over a set of $N$ points $p_i\in P$. These $(u,s)$ are subjugate to the following constraints:
$$-w \leq u \leq w$$
$$-1 \leq s \leq w - 1$$
After reordering, I have defined my problem in the following manner:
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\|c_i - \bar{c_i}\|_2^2 = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\|c
_i - p_i - u - s(c_0 - p_i)|_2^2 = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\| \alpha_i- u - s\beta_i\|_2^2$$
If I move to a vector\matrix form:
$$f(x) = \| \overrightarrow{\alpha_i} - \overrightarrow{u} - s\overrightarrow{\beta_i}\|_2^2$$
Here, $\overrightarrow{\alpha_i}, \overrightarrow{u},\overrightarrow{\beta_i}\in\mathbb{R}^N$. I have ordered the following $F$ matrix:
$$F\cdot \overrightarrow{\theta} = \overrightarrow{\alpha}, F\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times2}, \overrightarrow{\theta} = \begin{bmatrix}
    u \\
    s \\
  \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times1}, \overrightarrow{\alpha}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times1}$$.
In $F$, each row is composed in the following manner:
$$F = \begin{bmatrix}
                      -1 &\beta_0\\
                      -1 &\beta_1\\
                      \vdots &\vdots\\
                      -1 &\beta_{N-1}\\
      \end{bmatrix},$$
and $\overrightarrow{\alpha}$ is defined using:
$$\overrightarrow{\alpha} = \begin{bmatrix}
                      \alpha_0\\
                      \alpha_1\\
                      \vdots\\
                      \alpha_{N-1}\\
      \end{bmatrix}.$$
According to this link, I now have to compose a new matrix using $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} - \lambda_i(\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial u}) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial s} - \lambda_i(\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial s}) = 0$, and set more equations in the form of matrix-rows using the constraints. I know that the constraints will be active only on one side of the interval (give $w\neq0$). I am not sure how to construct and derive the matrix. Is this at all the correct approach?
